# How can you make use a variable as a file type in Swift

Tags: swift

In the code below how could you use variable controllerFileTypeIs to dynamically choose which file to use when opening a new view controller?

```
//MainViewController.swift

var variableForHomePage:HomeMenuViewController!
var variableForEntryViewController:EntryViewController!

var isHome:Bool = false
var controllerFileTypeIs:UIViewController?
var vcIdentifier:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if isHome {
        controllerFileTypeIs = variableForHomePage
        vcIdentifier = "homeSB"
    } else {
        controllerFileTypeIs = variableForEntryViewController
        vcIdentifier = "entrySB"
    }

    var vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcIdentifier) as! controllerFileTypeIs
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already set the storyboard identifier for your controller, so no need to type cast anything, just do it in the following way.

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcIdentifier!)
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```